# Why the video is not shown on my computer?

Tags: usb, usb-storage

There is a video in my USB device probably of the size (7.27 GB - 2.87 GB = 4.4 GB) 
[image]

But when I open it, I just see a 1 KB .cm0013 file

[image]

If I connect the device to a TV, I can easily watch the video but no video is shown when the USB device is connected to my computer.

---

**Edit:**

- The TV device is SAMSUNG and the [.cm0013 file](https://fileinfo.com/extension/cm0013) is related to it.
- The USB device is a [Dataland chico 8 GB](http://dataland.com.tw/products/Product.aspx?pid=chico8gb) one.

Hidden files are visible

[image]

And there's no seperate partition in the device

[image]

Comment: What is the file extension? Have you tried a different computer?  How did you get the video file on the USB drive to begin with?

Comment: I found a site that indicates the file is related to samsung tvs. http://en.filedict.com/cm0013-samsung-smart-tv-index-file-2047/ I dont see a reference to why or how it may be related to hiding your larger file. I am sure they are related though. You did not mention what type of usb device. What type of device, just a thumb drive?

Comment: And the file is probably hidden by default. Have you tried with hidden files visible? However, seeing the file doesn't mean you can play it in a computer. If it is like suggested in the answer below a Samsung TV's proprietary format you probably can't reproduce it anywhere else.

Comment: Is your first screenshot supposed to show that there is a "2.78 GB video in my USB devise"?

Comment: The first image shows that the `F:` drive has 2.87 GB free of 7.27 GB, which suggests that there’s 4.40 GB of content.   The second image ostensibly shows the root of the `F:` drive, containing a single file of only 1 KB.   I agree that the question is missing a lot of information.

Comment: @Sickest:  Why did you change “Television” to “TV” but leave two copies of “devise” alone?

Comment: @scott, Happy??

Comment: @Sickest Yes, the file isn't shown neither on my laptop nor on my sister's laptop. The USB with the video on it is a gift from an organization for which I played music in a ceremony.

Comment: @RoDrop Yes, I know that CM0013 file is related to the Television. Before installing the device to my laptop, I watched the video last night on my Samsung TV. And about USB device it's a Dataland Chico 8 GB USB (http://dataland.com.tw/products/Product.aspx?pid=chico8gb)

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I've edited my question

Comment: @MrWhite I've edited my question

Comment: @Scott I've edited my question. Tell me if more information is needed

Answer (score 3):

A [`.cm0013 file`](https://fileinfo.com/extension/cm0013), created by select Samsung Smart TV is an index to the files located on external storage medium, such as a USB flash drive. The file is a *pointer* to the actual location on the disk of video data, similar to the [`.cda file`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.cda_file) on an audio CD, and is not the video data itself.

Look for other files on the USB drive, since clearly, **something** is taking up about 4.4 GB of the ~8 GTB on it. The drive might have hidden files, or even another partition, which you are not seeing in File Explorer. [Turn on](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028316/windows-view-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-10) `Show hidden files, folders and drives`. Also try [searching using `DIR`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir):

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `cmd` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to get a CMD dialog as Administrator.
- Type `f:` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to move to the F: drive, assuming that is where the USB flash is shown.
- Type `dir \a:h` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to find hidden files.
- Type `dir \a:i` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to find un-indexed files.
- Type `dir \a:s` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to find system files.
- Type `dir \a:d` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to find other folders (directories).

If the video file still is hidden, it might be on another partition, which you can view in Disk Management: Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `diskmg` in the *Search* box and select *diskmgt.msc*.

[image]

Comment: Additional partitions cannot explain space marked as “used”.

Comment: I've edited my question.